# How to detect when Excel has been closed (Office interop)

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

Microsoft Word interop offers a `Quit` event to detect when the user closes it:

```
var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var events = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)word;
events.Quit += Word_Quit;
```

Is there something similar for Microsoft Excel? I found a similar interface, but unfortunately there's no `Quit` event:

```
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var events = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_Event)excel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hack, but it works for my purpose. Just keep a reference to the Excel / Word document, and periodically try to access a simple property. If it fails, the document has most likely been closed:

```
try
{
    if (this.workbook != null)
    {
        var count = this.workbook.Worksheets.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        var count = this.wordDocument.Content.StoryLength;
    }
}
catch
{
    // Office has been closed
}
```

Comment: This checks if a specific file is open. You can use [WorkbookBeforeClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.workbookbeforeclose.aspx) to track that. But closing document does not mean closing application.

Comment: @BrakNicku WorkbookBeforeClose fires before the user has a chance to save the document. So we don't have the exact moment when the document is closed.

Comment: In event handler you can suppress standard save dialog (`DisplayAlerts = false`) and show your own - this way you can know the exact moment of closing document, but the main problem is that closing document<>closing application, so this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @BrakNicku You're right, I should have been more precise. In the environment of our application, closing the document is the same as closing Excel, since the user cannot open other documents or start Excel on its own.

Comment: Even though you most likely don't need it anymore, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58643395)'s how to properly detect a workbook being closed after the saving message prompts without resorting to messing with `DisplayAlerts` and having your custom message (if you can listen to those events through interop that is, else programmatically add the VBA code to the VBE with interop).