# VBA : Get the user's choice from the save msgbox before closing the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project in which I need to fire a macro if the user closes the workbook. To do this I use the BeforeClose event.

However, the msgbox "Would you like to save your modifications [...]" fires after the BeforeClose event. This is a huge problem since the user can change his mind and click on Cancel, which invalidate what the macro is supposed to do. (The macro should delete some data in an other opened workbook, but only and only if the actual workbook is definitely closed)

I've try and searched many things without success.

So if there anyway to get the response from the msgbox that triggers ? Or just  don't display the alert ? (Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not seem to work in such a scenario)

Comment: Why such a message to be needed, since the user choice may ruin what you need to do? If you only want to show "consideration" to the user, let it there, but do not make `Cancel = True`, even if it choose an option he shouldn't... Not the message box stops the workbook to be closed...

Comment: I don't get it. The message is the automatic displayed one just  before closing the workbook, and if the user hits cancel is actually cancels the closing of the workbook

Comment: Ups... I thought it is a custom message. Then, you simple have to use `Workbook.Close True`. It will save it without asking for confirmation...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643395/how-to-detect-when-a-workbook-is-closing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think that **ThisWorkbook.Saved = true** will do what you need. No prompt will appear and then with yourMacro you can do whatever you need, you even can save the workbook.

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saved

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Call youMacro
End Sub
```